# black window in simulator -collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

The code is a simple collection view with a bunch of images 
I ran it and Xcode doesn't argue about anything but the simulator shows a black screen after running the app.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

     return recipePhotos.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *identifier =@"Cell";
   UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   // Configure the cell
   UIImageView * recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
   recipeImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: UIImage *recImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: first check whether this non null

Comment: have you registered the cell in viewdidload?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check collection view datasource outlet, maybe it was not connected with your controller?
2. Check receipeImageView is not nil.
3. Did you register your UICollectionViewCell with identifier @"Cell"?

Comment: yes I did but it wasn't about cell registeration .
problem solved by commenting out one line that Xcode provides by default. thank you any way

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want black background, you have to set

```
collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Then you must register the cell

```
 UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"yournibname" bundle:nil];
 [collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

Both need to be implemented in viewDidLoad method